# Why is that when I use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect the image rotates?

Tags: iphone, ios4

This is my code:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(size.width / 4, size.height / 4 , 
                         size.width / 2, size.width / 2); 

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([[picture objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] CGImage], rect);

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

but the image rotates.

How can I solve it?

Comment: It would be nice if you added your solution below or if you selected the answer below if it is the correct answer.  Remember, StackOverflow works because people provide solutions, not just questions.

Answer (score 0):

The returns the original image UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage.
 The easy way is to use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` but before you mast set your ImagePicker to allow editing.

Comment: can you please answer your question @AprilKwong

Answer (score 0):

Reason: 
Every UIImage has an orientation, defaults to UIImageOrientationUp. But orientation of the image you captured with camera ([picture objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]) is not always UIImageOrientationUp. 
So, if u simply copy image with [UIImage imageWithCGImage:], u will lost the orientation info.
Use [UIImage imageWithCGImage: scale: orientation:] instead.

F.Y.I
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#Constants
In Constants Section, the Docset gives a sample image for each UIImageOrientation.

Comment: This hardly counts as an answer. You should really put a little more effort into an answer.
1. How to do it.
2. Why doing it this way.
3. Where can the reader find more information on that matter (reference link).